# TypeScript General Constructs reference guide

Tags: javascript, typescript

On the TypeScript GitHub page, there's a document that contains coding guidelines, explaining the do's and don't's of TypeScript: [TypeScript Coding Guidelines](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Coding-guidelines#general-constructs). It says the following:

> For a variety of reasons, we avoid certain constructs, and use some of our own. Among them:
>
> 1. Do not use ECMAScript 5 functions; instead use those found in core.ts.
> 2. Do not use for..in statements; instead, use ts.forEach, ts.forEachKey and ts.forEachValue. Be aware of their slightly different semantics.
> 3. Try to use ts.forEach, ts.map, and ts.filter instead of loops when it is not strongly inconvenient.

This makes sense to me. TypeScript obviously has a built-in library containing some ES5 functions optimised to be used within TypeScript. What I was wondering is if there's some kind of function reference like jQuery's own documentation, where each method has an explanation, example and other info regarding compatibility and version differences.

I've searched for this on the TypeScript website and on Google, but Google insists I'm searching for 'Generic Constructs' instead of 'General Constructs' (which Microsoft calls its built-in TS library). I can't really find anything related to the general constructs that they're talking about on the site, except for the core.ts file of course, which contains the general constructs.

Does anyone have a source I could use for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coding guideline you refer to is the internal guideline for the TypeScript compiler project. It is not necessary the coding guideline of how you should write your project with TypeScript.

You should think of TypeScript as just JavaScript with a gradual type system.

The closer you keep your code close to JavaScript the better.

The TypeScript handbook would be a good starting point.

You can also check out the deep dive guide and other style guides available on GitHub.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that (:

Comment: Yet it's marked as accepted answer
it is not actually an answer to the question (
Would be interested of TS team's implementation of forEach / ForEachKey... too
(yes I saw their disclamer)